# Qt AudioOutput timing Problems

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, audio, wav

I have a problem with QAudioOutput and pushing chunks in time into the output device. I open up an QAudioOuput with a QIODevice under the hood and push chunks from a wave file stream into it. First I used QTimer and depending on the sample rate of the file I used the timeout signal to push a chunk into the buffer. The problem is if I do so the audio output is linked to the performance of the threat the QAudioOuput is nested in.

So I decided to put my "audiotimer" into a thread and recall process() after putting the thread into sleep for the specific interval. Everytime I call process I emit a signal for the other classes to catch and start processing audio data. This ends up in a crash caused by a segfault when emmiting the signal.

Due to the fact that the QT 5.x documentation is not very precise how to use the QAudioDevice in push mode I need to know how to properly use a timer to put wave chunks into the output in QT.

Just to let you know I'm having different audio sinks and I merge them into one audio output.